# Disabling warning prompt when opening a .doc file in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am getting this prompt in Outlook every time I try to open a `.doc` file.

> You should only open attachments from a trustworthy source prompt when opening a .doc file

There is a checkbox that says

```
Always ask before opening this type of file
```

which is checked and grayed out. The user does not have local admin privileges. I was wondering if there was a registry edit to resolve this.

Comment: I dont think this is controlled at your local machine , this is probably controlled from the exchange server . So a reg edit wouldnt help you

Comment: You can enable the checkbox if you have an admin account (Win 7 and Vista) so it isn't a server side issue. As you say, it should be possible with a registry tweak.

Comment: It is not a duplicate you re referring to! Outlook behavior is different than in Windows!

Comment: Microsoft has a direct answer for this specific Outlook issue:
As this is a computer-wide change, you can only change that option when you are running Outlook as an Administrator.
1. Close Outlook.
2. Hold CTRL+SHIFT while clicking on the Outlook icon.
3. Accepts the security prompt and/or provide administrator credentials.
4. Open the attachment and untick the "Always ask..." box.
5. Close Outlook and start it normally.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/how-to-disable-the-warning-on-opening-any/b424facc-3855-4467-8225-cb0c9de44c11

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with one of our users, I just change "Microsoft Word" Trust Center Settings to Enable Protected View for Outlook. To do so, run Microsoft Word, go to File => Options, in open window go to Trust Center then Trust Center Settings and in Protect View settings select "Enable Protected View for Outlook". After that you should be able to open doc files without any prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Your user is seeing the results of the [Attachment Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/information-about-the-attachment-manager-in-microsoft-windows-c48a4dcd-8de5-2af5-ee9b-cd795ae42738).  You can

- Turn the Attachment Manager off (or, rather, tell it not to save zone information in files) with a group policy setting.
- If you trust the site from which the user download the document, add the site to the list of trusted Internet sites.  ([Raymond Chen's preferred option.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110504-00/?p=10743))
- Show the user how to select **Unblock** on the file’s *Properties* tab.
- Fiddle around at a low level with tools like [streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) or [AlternateStreamView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html) to delete the data stream that comprises the zone identifier.

Comment: The question is about Outlook while you provide a solution regarding opening files from the Windows Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925757#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways.

Comment: This is an ancient post, but please consider expanding your answer to make it self-contained. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful. It's better to include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading. Thanks.